# I cant flash a phone because it's locked

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader-lock

I cant flash my cousin's phone because it's locked and it keeps saying "erase is not allowed in locked state"
it's a POCO X3 pro and it got bricked for no reason so I tried everything, and now I tried to flash it but it doesn't let me do that, because it's locked, i cant unlock it because i can't access the ROM, i don't know what to do.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/no-auth-firehose.4381683/

Comment: never installed custom ROM

Comment: sadly i cant pay

Comment: no worry you can still use it as paperweight

Comment: what do you mean?